# What does the name "Sirach" mean?

Tags: hebrew, names, aramaic, apocrypha

The apocryphal text dubbed "Eccleasiaticus" (also known as The Book of Sirach) is purported to be written by a man by the name of Ben Sira or Shimon ben Yeshua ben Eliezer ben Sira.  I was looking into the meaning of the name of Sirach but could not find anything.  Does anyone know what Sirach means?  (Bonus: Could you explain what Sira means as well if able?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Sira#Name):

> Sirach is the Greek form of the family name Sira. It adds the letter Chi, an addition like that in Hakel-dama-ch in Acts 1:19.

According to Da'at Mikra on Ezra 2:61, footnote 103:

> פירוש השם הקוץ כמשמעו: קוץ. והשווה אליו את השם בן-סירא, שאף הוא כנראה נגזר מלשון סירים - קוצים.

Translation:
The meaning of the name "Hakotz" is as it is: a thorn. And compare to it the name "Ben-Sira", which was also probably derived from "sirim" - thorns*.

---

<sup>*</sup> Sirim are a type of thorn in Hebrew, such as in [Nachum 1:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nahum.1.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - "כִּי עַד **סִירִים** סְבֻכִים וּכְסָבְאָם סְבוּאִים אֻכְּלוּ כְּקַשׁ יָבֵשׁ מָלֵא" and in [Tehillim 58:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.58.10?lang=bi) - "בְּטֶרֶם יָבִינוּ **סִּירֹתֵיכֶם** אָטָד כְּמוֹ חַי כְּמוֹ חָרוֹן יִשְׂעָרֶנּוּ".